# angular why the value is not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm thinking in using angular, and found my first problem. Probably it is a begginer problem.

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {


angular
    .module('account.controllers')
    .controller('CreateController', CreateController);

CreateController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Account'];

/**
 * @namespace CreateController
 */
function CreateController($location, $scope, Account) {
    vm = this;
    vm.model = Account.get(1).then(getSuccessFn);


    /**
     * @name postsSuccessFn
     * @desc populate with the data of the current account
     */
    function getSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        vm.account = data.data;
    }
}
})();
```

And here is my form:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<h1>Register</h1>

<div class="well">
  <form role="form" name="accountForm" ng-submit="vm.create()" ng-controller="CreateController">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="create__name">name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="create__name" ng-model="vm.account.name" placeholder="John" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="create__payment">Operation Cost</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="create__payment" ng-model="vm.account.payment" placeholder="15.00" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="create__member">member</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="create__member" ng-model="vm.account.member" placeholder="Golden" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

So, the page loads fine, the data is retrieved, the vm.account variable is with the correct values, but the values are not shown, it remains the default values. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using controller-as syntax?

To reference `vm` inside the `HTML`, you should use the controller-as syntax. if you are using `ngRoute` be sure to add the `controllerAs` property on the route configuration object. If you are using the `ngController` directive, do this: `ng-controller="CreateController as vm"`

Also in my testing it only worked when I added the `var` keyword before the `vm` variable declaration, like this:

`var vm = this;`

Here is the code I used to test it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="account.controllers">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>stack overflow</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script>
        (function () {
            angular
                .module('account.controllers', [])
                .controller('CreateController', CreateController)
                .service('Account', ['$q', function($q) {
                    var srvc = this;
                    // emulate $http response
                    srvc.get = function () {
                        return $q.when({ data : {
                            name: 'Test',
                            member: 'Silver',
                            payment: 10
                            }
                        });
                    };
                }]);
            CreateController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Account'];
            /**
             * @namespace CreateController
             */
            function CreateController($location, $scope, Account) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.model = Account.get(1).then(getSuccessFn);
                /**
                 * @name postsSuccessFn
                 * @desc populate with the data of the current account
                 */
                function getSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                    vm.account = data.data;
                }
            }
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" ng-controller="CreateController as vm">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <div class="well">
      <form role="form" name="accountForm" ng-submit="vm.create()" ng-controller="CreateController">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="create__name">name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="create__name" ng-model="vm.account.name" placeholder="John" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="create__payment">Operation Cost</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="create__payment" ng-model="vm.account.payment" placeholder="15.00" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="create__member">member</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="create__member" ng-model="vm.account.member" placeholder="Golden" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just put the var and nothing happened :(

Comment: which version of angular are you using? Also, can you share some of the service code?

Comment: One thing that crossed my mind is if the `data` parameter has the payload inside a `data` property. Try to change the line where you assign the response to  just `vm.account = data;`

Comment: Wow! It worked! :) The issue was with the data property. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using controllerAs syntax right. Fix it this way:

```
ng-controller="CreateController as vm"
```

otherwise `vm` is a property of the scope object, which you never set.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :)Done. But it the data still not show :(

Comment: What is `Account.get(1)`? Is `vm.account = data.data;` gets populated?

Comment: Yes, I checked with firebug and it gets populated. the get(1) is a method of the account service. the 1 is the key.

Comment: Here is my [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LDCFlQILnANVmmlbeq6F?p=preview) I created, so it should work. Probably something else prevents from working in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. The issue was with the data like rodrigopedra sugested. With only data, instead of data.data worked fine.